# Practical uses for Structural Types?

Tags: scala

Structural types are one of those "wow, cool!" features of Scala.  However, For every example I can think of where they might help, implicit conversions and dynamic mixin composition often seem like better matches. What are some common uses for them and/or advice on when they are appropriate?

Comment: This is still an issue I'm trying to understand better, and so far I haven't seen a convincing case for structural types.  Wouldn't implicits be a better fit even for the canonical `close()` example?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498954/why-do-compile-time-generative-techniques-for-structural-typing-prevent-separate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aside from the rare case of classes which provide the same method but aren't related nor do implement a common interface (for example, the `close()` method -- `Source`, for one, does not extend `Closeable`), I find no use for structural types with their present restriction. If they were more flexible, however, I could well write something like this:

```
def add[T: { def +(x: T): T }](a: T, b: T) = a + b
```

which would neatly handle numeric types. Every time I think structural types might help me with something, I hit that particular wall.

**EDIT**

However unuseful I find structural types myself, the *compiler*, however, uses it to handle anonymous classes. For example:

```
implicit def toTimes(count: Int) = new {
  def times(block: => Unit) = 1 to count foreach { _ => block }
}

5 times { println("This uses structural types!") }
```

The object resulting from (the implicit) `toTimes(5)` is of type `{ def times(block: => Unit) }`, ie, a structural type.

I don't know if Scala does that for every anonymous class -- perhaps it does. Alas, that is one reason why doing pimp my library that way is slow, as structural types use reflection to invoke the methods. Instead of an anonymous class, one should use a real class to avoid performance issues in pimp my library.

Comment: I tried to get your first example to work -- The best I came up with was def add[T <% { def +(x: T): R },R](a: T, b: T) : R = a + b, but the compiler complained about the structural type referring to R

Comment: @Vasil I'm getting careless... :-( Thanks for the help!

Comment: Transparent/Idiomatic reflection? Obviously, when there's no option but use reflection.

Answer (score 3):

Structural types are very cool constructs in Scala.  I've used them to represent multiple unrelated types that share an attribute upon which I want to perform a common operation without a new level of abstraction.

I have heard one argument against structural types from people who are strict about an application's architecture.  They feel it is dangerous to apply a common operation across types without an associative trait or parent type, because you then leave the rule of what type the method should apply to open-ended.  Daniel's `close()` example is spot on, but what if you have another type that requires different behavior?  Someone who doesn't understand the architecture might use it and cause problems in the system.

Answer (score 2):

I think structural types are one of these features that you don't need that often, but *when* you need it, it helps you a lot. One area where structural types really shine is "retrofitting", e.g. when you need to glue together several pieces of software you have no source code for and which were not intended for reuse. But if you find yourself using structural types a lot, you're probably doing it wrong.

**[Edit]**

Of course implicits are often the way to go, but there are cases when you can't: Imagine you have a mutable object you can modify with methods, but which hides important parts of it's state, a kind of "black box". Then you have to work somehow with this object.

Another use case for structural types is when code relies on naming conventions without a common interface, e.g. in machine generated code. In the JDK we can find such things as well, like the StringBuffer / StringBuilder pair (where the common interfaces Appendable and CharSequence are *way* to general).

Comment: Thanks.  Could you comment on when structural types are more effective than implicit conversions when dealing w/ closed source libraries?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "black box" example?  How does structural typing help in this use case?

Answer (score 1):

Structural types gives some benefits of dynamic languages to a statically linked language, specifically loose coupling. If you want a method `foo()` to call instance methods of class `Bar`, you don't need an interface or base-class that is common to both `foo()` and `Bar`. You can define a structural type that `foo()` accepts and whose `Bar` has no clue of existence. As long as `Bar` contains methods that match the structural type signatures, `foo()` will be able to call.

It's great because you can put `foo()` and `Bar` on distinct, completely unrelated libraries, that is, with no common referenced contract. This reduces linkage requirements and thus further contributes for loose coupling.

In some situations, a structural type can be used as an alternative to the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern, because it offers the following advantages:

- Object identity is preserved (there is no separate object for the adapter instance, at least in the semantic level).
- You don't need to instantiate an adapter - just pass a `Bar` instance to `foo()`.
- You don't need to implement wrapper methods - just declare the required signatures in the structural type.
- The structural type doesn't need to know the actual instance class or interface, while the adapter must know `Bar` so it can call its methods. This way, a single structural type can be used for many actual types, whereas with adapter it's necessary to code multiple classes - one for each actual type.

The only drawback of structural types compared to adapters is that a structural type can't be used to translate method signatures. So, when signatures doesn't match, you must use adapters that will have some translation logic. I particularly don't like to code "intelligent" adapters because in many times they are more than just adapters and cause increased complexity. If a class client needs some additional method, I prefer to simply add such method, since it usually doesn't affect footprint.